# update cells in excel using access database

Tags: database, excel

I am trying to make a task easier for my wife that currently has to be done by hand.  Where she works she sees clients that come in for help, and she documents what help each client gets.  Every month she has to compile a statistics sheet that lists how many clients she saw, how many of each race, how many of each gender, age range, etc.

I have created the monthly statistics sheet that she uses in Excel which has the above mentioned information on it. I am also creating a database that has two tables.  One table is a client table, and one is a table that will keep track of visits.

What I would like to do is have the database update the excel sheet.

For example, if a 25 year old female comes in, I want the visits table to add to the spreadsheet that a white female in that age range of 20 - 30 came in.  If a 40 year old black female comes in, I want the database to increment the female count on the spread sheet, and put a 1 in the race cell for black, and a 1 in the cell for the age range of 30-40.

Simply put, any time the visits table is updated, I want it to increment the appropriate cell in the Excel spreadsheet.

Is this possible or would it be too complicated? Is there another way that I could do this that would be easier?

Comment: It sounds to me like the queries you need could just be done inside of access if thats where the data is being stored.  You could create a link to it using either get external data or something like [Power Query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) which is a free add on from microsoft.

Comment: I think best would be to inverse your logic. Don't update the Excel file from Access, but rather use Access as a datasource for your excel sheet. Either directly or via some VBA code

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not a database tool. If you have your heart set on access/excel I would create an access form to enter data directly into an access database.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Data tab in excel, click "From Access" import the data onto one tab then create functions on another to summarize the data. For your age range example you could use the countifs function have one criteria be that they are female and a second AND criteria of AND(age >=20, age <=30)

```
=countifs(rangeWithGender, "Female", AND(rangeWithAge >=20, rangeWithAge <=30))
```